# How to prevent animation on certain element when transition from one activity to another activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently building an app that lock other app, and in the app, there's two activity:

- One that list all of the installed app on the user device to allow the user to lock
- And another for the settings page, where the user can change password, set theme, etc.

On the top, there's an action bar where it display thing like the app name, the search icon

On the bottom, there's two button to allow user to move between those activities

And in the middle is the content of the current activity.

[This is what the layout would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8hVY.png)

And I want to transition from the `installed app` activity to the `settings` activity, so I search on Internet for one and here's what I've come up:

```kotlin
findViewById<Button>(R.id.setting_button).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(this, SettingActivity::class.java))
})
```

It does work, and I does expect the action bar and the buttons below to animate, but it's not something I don't want.

So, is there a way to prevent the action bar and the buttons below from animating?

Comment: Use a single activity and multiple fragments. Keep the toolbar ad buttons in the top level layout of the activity with the fragment host inside that same layout.

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
startActivity(Intent(this, SettingActivity::class.java))
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

This will stop the animation.

Comment: This stop animation completely, I just want the action bar and the buttons below to not animate, not the middle part too

Comment: @greg1982 For ActionBar  add
 getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);

Also for buttons, Go to Layout file of activity, Add android:animateLayoutChanges to false in root layout.

remove this.
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);